# How to retrieve the folder name from Google Cloud Storage bucket with sub-folder

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

We have a GCS bucket with a subfolder at url https://storage.googleapis.com/our-bucket/path-to-subfolder. This sub-folder contains files

```
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""
    bucket_name = "my_bucket"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
```

Using this function i can extract the whole directory

```
'folder1/data.csv',
 ' folder1/data2.csv',
 ' folder1/data4.csv',
folder2/data3.csv',
 ' folder2/data5.csv',
 ' folder3/data.csv',
```

Instead of that is it possible to retrieved the folder name

```
Output :
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

Comment: I have posted the answer. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

As your question description doesn’t match the title of the stackoverflow question. Considering the described issue “is it possible to retrieved the folder name” below is the solution you can try with

```
     def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix,delimiter=None):
     storage_client = storage.Client() 
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name,prefix=prefix,delimiter=delimiter)
```

For details you can check the [Document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#storage_list_files_with_prefix-python).